# Inner join in solr raises cannot parse error

Tags: sql, solr, lucene, inner-join

I have the following sql request

```
SELECT "people".* FROM "people" INNER JOIN "match_scores" ON "match_scores"."person_id" = "people"."id" WHERE (match_scores.job_id = 859 and match_scores.score >= 25)
```

I would like to use solr for searching and this is my request

```
http://<code>hostname:8983/solr/select?q=*:*&fq=
({!join from=person_id_i to=id_i}job_id_i:859 AND {!join from=person_id_i to=id_i}score_e:{25\\.0 TO *})
```

It raises the following error:

```
"msg": "org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'score_e:': Encountered \"<EOF>\" at line 1, column 8.\nWas expecting one of:\n    <BAREOPER> ...\n    \"(\" ...\n    \"*\" ...\n    <QUOTED> ...\n    <TERM> ...\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\n    <WILDTERM> ...\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\n    \"[\" ...\n    \"{\" ...\n    <LPARAMS> ...\n    <NUMBER> ...\n    ",
```

Comment: Does `fq={!join from=person_id_i to=id_i}job_id_i:859 AND score_e:{25.0 TO *]` work? As far as I remember there shouldn't be a reason to add two identical join-conditions, since you can filter the condition on multiple statements. Since the error is a parse error, start by simplifying your query to find out what generates the error (I assume that the double backslash is from copying the statement out from code)

Comment: @MatsLindh It works like a charm! Thank you very much! You can write an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to attempt multiple joins to the same collection (and I'm not sure if multiple in a single `fq` would work anyway) - the one you're doing can filter on both conditions:

```
{!join from=person_id_i to=id_i}job_id_i:859 AND score_e:{25.0 TO *]
```